# Jquery if/else statement to switch between iframe, css, and style elements

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, if-statement, dynamic

Okay, so I am building a website for my company, and I feel we are doing something a little unique, because the past three days I have been googleing what to do, and I have turned up near nothing.  I am also below novice, but I am trying to learn.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('yea');
    $("spaceButton").click(function(){
        var fileref=document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", "css/galaxy.css");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        if ($('element').videoIframe == 0) 
        {
            $("('galaxy').hide()");
            $("#videoIframe").appendChild ('head');
        };
        else
        {
            $("("videoIframe").hide()");    
            $("<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/galaxy.css" type="text/css" media="all">").appendChild('head');
        };
        return false;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

    });
});
```

EDIT: 
in addition to what @barmar said, I changed the link rel in the else statement with \'s.  It is now running.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert('yea');
$("#spaceButton").click(function(){
var fileref = $("<link>", { href: "css/galaxy.css", type: "text/css" });
fileref.setAttribute("href", "css/galaxy.css") ;
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        if ($('element').attr("videoIframe") == 0) 
        {
            $('galaxy').hide();
            $("#videoIframe").appendChild ('head');
        }
        else 
        {
            $("videoIframe").hide();    
            $("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/galaxy.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\">").appendChild('head');
        };
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: And this is my first post here, I am sorry that that last bit got cut off from the code block.

Thank you Barmar!

Comment: Please 1) what want you do? 2) use correct line indention 3) correct line $("("videoIframe").hide()");

Comment: Welcome to SO! Cleaned up your line indents, removed an errant ";", otherwise same as original for the sake of the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I just edited what I would like to do.  I don't know what you mean about line indentation, I believe it was fixed by a moderator.  And I don't know how to fix that line?

Comment: @PapaNer once a user reaches a certain amount of "reputation" they can edit a post. I just edited yours by indenting your markup to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Sorry, I am incredibly new here.  Most everything I've searched for an have been able to implement has come from this site, so I wanted to try it out.

Comment: No need to apologize, just explaining the situation. I would recommend browsing the jQuery questions to get a better idea of jQuery syntax.

Comment: Also in the process of doing that.  This site is really a goldmine of information.  Hopefully I'll be standing on my own legs in time and be able to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a condition test on the `else` line, only on `if` lines. If you want to perform another test, it should be `else if`. Also, you don't put a `;` before `else`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('yea');
    $("spaceButton").click(function(){
        var fileref=document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", "css/galaxy.css") ;;
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        if ($('element').videoIframe == 0) 
        {
            $("('galaxy').hide()");
            $("#videoIframe").appendChild ('head');
        }
        else if ($('element').galaxy == 0)
        {
            $("("videoIframe").hide()");    
            $("<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/galaxy.css" type="text/css" media="all">").appendChild('head');
        }
        return false;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

    });
});
```

Other issues:

1. jQuery objects don't have `.videoIframe` or `.galaxy` properties. Maybe it should be `.attr("videoIframe")`.
2. I have no idea what you're intending by quoting `$("('galaxy').hide()")`. It should be `$('galaxy').hide()`.  Similarly with `$("("videoIframe").hide()")`, whose parenthese aren't balanced, either.
3. You have a statement after `return false`. Once the function returns, nothing after that executes.
4. I think you're missing `#` before the IDs in several selectors, e.g. `$("spaceButton")` should be `$("#spaceButton")`. Without this, it's looking for an element like `<spaceButton>`.
5. Why are you calling `document.createElement` when you use jQuery? Use the jQuery element constructor `var fileref = $("<link>", { href: "css/galaxy.css", type: "text/css" });`.
6. Don't put `;` after `}` that are used for program blocks.

You really need to learn basic Javascript and jQuery, you have mistakes on almost every line of this code.

Comment: Man, I didn't even stop to consider.  Thanks for that heads up.  I am still getting an error, but it just says "SyntaxError: syntax error: else"

Comment: You had a `;` on the line before `else`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I've only just been introduced to jQuery three days ago, and as I said, I am below novice at programming.  They pretty much tossed me this project because it would be a way for me to learn a bit of what I'll be doing as well as giving me work with a flexible deadline.

Comment: And none of the other programmers there can guide you through the basics, you're totally on your own and have to depend on the kindness of Internet strangers?

Comment: Well actually, I am in here by myself for the whole week.  The person who has been working with me is taking care of his post-surgery wife.  I just don't want to sit idly by, and I need way more knowledge to complete this task than I have.

Comment: Also, thank you for answering.  I can only assume it's annoying to see such basic errors, and I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to fix the `selectors`. Like `$("spaceButton");` - is this an id, or this is a class? Next, what is the `$("element");` selector? I think you mean `$(element)`, from the examples; you have to declare what is your target selector. And at last i want to advise you to learn a bit more about `jQuery` and `JavaScript`. This snippet is full of logical and syntax errors.

Comment: Well I am actually in the process of applied learning.  I am not at all saying I'm great at this, I'm just trying to get to get my feet wet a little more each day.  Thank you for your answer.